# Something is wrong with the appearance

Tags: graphics

I alredy install Ubuntu desktop the version of 32 b and I think something is wrong with the appearance in Ubuntu. When i do some actions as run the ubuntus menu or just try to shut down the computer my screen starts to go some slowly and its like it cant be show it as it is.
In trying to do some actions like going to the menu of ubuntu, to get any app, or just trying to shut down the system, the computer begins to split into lines that is, these windows appear as divided into lines, and is not shown as should be.

Answer (score -1):

First, do not use 32bit Ubuntu with a hardware that can support 64 bit. People moved to 64bit fully and many do not test 32bit packages as well as 64bit.
Second, do you have your video card properly configured? Seems not. If it is NVIDIA, install vendor's drivers.